# Dispaly an Error Message on unsuccessful POST function

Tags: apex, lightning, error, post

I have a requirement where the user is updating a table and when he/she clicks on the Save button a POST service is called and the data gets saved.
The requirement is now enhanced where by the user will get an error message on the front-end if the Save has been unsuccessful.
How do I display an error message on the failure of save feature?

Thanks..:)

Comment: are you talking about visualforce or lightning? visualforce can use `ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,'something went wrong'));` method to display the message, lightning, you need to catch and re throw a `AuraHandledException('Error message to display in Lightning')`;
`

Comment: My mistake.. I am using Lightning component.. Can you please explain a bit more on how to use the line "AuraHandledException('Error message to display in Lightning'".. I am newbie into SFDC...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Lightning component, we are supposed to throw `AuraHandledException` to client with meaningful message. A quick example below:

```
try{
  // run your POST call here
} catch (Exception e)
{ 
  // call out function failed;
  throw new AuraHandledException('This is the message I want client browser to see');
}
```

For detailed explanation read here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2017/09/error-handling-best-practices-lightning-apex.html